# How to echo same content as in file?

Tags: bash

I have a file  content like below

```
cat file

Hello How are you ?
I am good
Watsapppp
bla bla
```

But When I am exporting and echoing its value/content , This gives everything in same line and bit different.

```
export filename=$(cat file)

echo $filename
Hello How are you 0 1 2 3 a m p q I am good Watsapppp bla bla
```

My Requirement in script is to print same content as in file.

Should be

```
$filename
Hello How are you ?
I am good
Watsapppp
bla bla
```

I mean when I pass the value of $filename , it should print above content

Comment: To send content in mail

Comment: Unless you know the precise implications, ***always*** quote your variables. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash, you can use `echo "$filename"` (between double quote), it will solve your problem.

Otherwize, you can always use, for looping on lines:

`mycommandgeneratinglines | while read line; do something_with $line; done`

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. What do you mean by "didn't expecting my solution"?

Comment: For your specific use case, why not ``cat file | mail -s subject user@domain.com``? Or any other mail tool/script which takes the mail content as standard input?

Comment: How are you building the email?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled: you have to use a command line (a line) which will contain ...  multiple lines. I think that the new lines will be dropped in any case.
In my opinion, you have to ask change to the Mail script author in order to accept content from stdin, or read content from a given file.

Comment: The "correct" code to read and print a file **verbatim** is: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < file` -- the `IFS=`, `read -r`, and quoted variable are all crucial parts of the process.

Comment: Indeed @glennjackman, but it won't fit into @Tom15 use case: ``script --var '<b>Contents:</b><br>'="$file2"' --from ..... --to.....``

Comment: True. In that case, I would use `script  --var '<b>Contents:</b><br>'="$(< file)"'  ...` and skip the variable entirely.

Comment: @glenn , this work when execute --> echo "$(< file)" , But doesn't work when sending mail like - '<b>Contents:</b><br>'="$(< file)"'  . Its still printing file content in same line in body of mail

Comment: In the script, assuming it's a shell script, you need to ensure you use quotes around your variables. Also, in your mail reader, check the source of the email (in gmail, it's the "dots" menu and "Show original") -- it could be you are sending it correctly but the mail reader is displaying it as HTML instead of plain text.